# Only display month name for Date.Now

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an Asp.net application which onclick of a button writes to my db. The issue I have is that for the date column all I want to be displayed is the month name and nothing else.

I have tried the below but I always get a message back saying "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

**First solution**

```
SqlPastPlaces.InsertParameters["Past_Place"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)txtDestination).Text;
SqlPastPlaces.InsertParameters["Month"].DefaultValue = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");

SqlPastPlaces.Insert();
```

**Second solution**

```
var CurrentMonth = String.Format("{0:MMMM}", DateTime.Now).ToString();
SqlPastPlaces.InsertParameters["Past_Place"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)txtDestination).Text;
SqlPastPlaces.InsertParameters["Month"].DefaultValue = CurrentMonth;

SqlPastPlaces.Insert();
```

The second solution, when I debug does give me 'October' but doesn't write to my database on my insert.

Both solutions die on the `SqlPastPlaces.Insert()`.  The column in my db is setup to be a `varchar`.

Also this is sat in my code behind.

Comment: Double-check that Month is indeed a varchar - it seems it is datetime; other place to check is SqlPastPlaces.InsertParameters["Month"] - check if it is defined as varchar parameter.

Comment: Verify that in your dataset and parameter declaration `Month` is not declared as `DateTime` even if you SQL column is `Varchar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cuprite, it was in my view. The following line was causing the issue.

```
<asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Month" />
```

By changing it to the following it now works

```
<asp:Parameter DbType="String" Name="Month" />
```

I completly forgot to change this bit.

Answer (score 0):

If the column you are inserting your data into is of type DateTime, you need to insert a valid date time. A string won't suffice.

```
SqlPastPlaces.InsertParameters["Month"].DefaultValue = DateTime.Now;
```

I wouldn't use a varchar or integer column for storing date portions, simply because it will cause a lot of additional work, once you need to change it to display the day and the month, or the year and the month.
Store the date and query / display only the data you need.